# Check UserName availability by using AJAX in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm creating a SignUp form,i want to add a feature to the form in which whenever a new user types an username in the text box, it should automatically check if the username is already taken or not(should compare it with usernames exist in SQL server database). I want to implement this feature using AJAX.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following jquery code, don't forget include jquery libraries

```
 $("#<%=txtJournalIdToMove.ClientID %>").blur(function () {
                var journalTextBoxId = '<%= this.txtJournalIdToMove.ClientID %>';
                var journalId = $("#" + journalTextBoxId).val();
                var params = '{"JournalId":"' + journalId + '"}';
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/PopulateVolumeNo",
                    data: params,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        // Replace the div's content with the page method's return.
                        var returnValue = data.d;
                        if (returnValue == null) {

                            alert("The given journal id does not exist or is in active in db.");
                        }
                        else {

                                 //If success do your functionality
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **onchange** or **on blur** event of a textbox. Here I used user-name-box as text box id

```
$.post('/Server/CheckAvailablity/', 
      {name:function(){return $('#user-name-box').val()},

      function(response){

       if(response.status="Y"){
       alert('available');
       }
      else{
       alert('not available');
       }
    }
);
```

> **In server side CheckAvailablity method prepare a JSON object like {"status":"Y"} and return**